# PostgreSQL: .psql_history to /dev/null

Tags: postgresql, psql

Rather than apply a `\set HISTFILE` command for every possible connection, we would like to have no `.psql_history` at all.  However, psql seems to dislike that:

```
% ln -s /dev/null ~/.psql_history
% psql
psql (8.4.8)
postgres=# select version();
...
postgres=# \q
could not save history to file "~/.psql_history": Not owner
```

There are folks out there willing to patch the source to get a fix but we prefer to be on a vanilla binary installation whenever possible:  to us, this isn't worth the hack.

*To clarify:* we don't want anything kept in this default filename, regardless of whether or not the user on this machine remembers (or knows) what options to pass.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `-n` (or synonym `--no-readline`) switch in [`psql`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/app-psql.html) command:

> Do not use readline for line editing and do not use the history. This
>   can be useful to turn off tab expansion when cutting and pasting.

**EDIT:**

As another way you can create `~/.psqlrc` file that contains `\set HISTFILE /dev/null`. With that psql doesn't create unwanted `.psql_history` file at all.

Comment: I understand this option but I'm trying to nullify the existence of this file completely.  I've clarified my question.  Thanks, though.

Comment: @Joe: I am not sure that I follow your question correctly, but what about `~/.psqlrc` config ?

Comment: I missed .psqlrc completely.  A quick test shows the .psql_history file doesn't get updated so that works; removing .psql_history and testing again gives no errors on exit, so that seems to be perfectly viable.  Thanks!