# Where is psql client history kept? (~/.psql_history non-existent!)

Tags: postgresql, psql

A password is visible in my psql prompt (by pushing up arrow to view previous inputted commands). So I would like to delete that entry from the psql client.

Other resources([1](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/04/15-practical-postgresql-database-adminstration-commands/), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654121/postgresql-psql-history-to-dev-null)) claim that psql client history is kept in is a `~/.psql_history` file, however this file is simply not there. (it's not in `.bash_history` either)

So **there must be another file where the history of psql prompt is kept, any ideas where?**

I log in to my prompt like this 
`sudo -u postgres psql my_db`

Note: I am working on `Ubuntu 12.04`

Comment: While I came to this question for the same reason, I don't think it's necessary to delete this command from this history file. The history file is only readable/writable by the `postgres` user (or root), and if you have access to that user, you can change whatever password you desire.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

When you use:

```
sudo -u postgres psql my_db
```

you run psql as the (Linux) user `postgres`, therefor the `.psql_history` file is in the home directory of the postgres user (e.g. `/home/postgres/.psql_history`), not in the home directory of the user you originally logged in with.

In some installations, the location of the `postgres` user's home directory is `/var/lib/postgresql`. You can check this by running:

```
grep postgres /etc/passwd | cut -d ':' -f 6
```

Comment: As a future reference: You could switch to the the `postgres` username by doing `sudo su postgres` and then do `cat ~/.psql_history`. But you don't even need to switch user if you do `~postgresql` and hit tab (tilde expansion), it then expands to `/var/lib/postgresql/`. The `.psql_history` file is located in the latter directory as well.

Comment: The real question is: why the `sudo` at all? `psql my_db postgres` will do the same thing.

Comment: The reason is that when I do `psql my_db postgres`, I get: `psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"`

Comment: I have no such file and no `/home/postgres` on my Postgres Docker container

Comment: Also in Centos it can be in /var/lib/pgsql

Comment: If you don't have a home directory for the postgres user, check my answer below. I use Ubuntu, but It's probably the same or similar on other distros.

Comment: @Suncatcher - I seem to specialise in late late answers. In a docker postgres container, you are usually signed in as root. So the psql history file is in /root. Make sure to ls with -a

Answer (score 13):

The filename is given by an internal variable named  `HISTFILE`.
Technically it doesn't have to be `~/.psql_history.`

Check the `~/.psqlrc` file for an alternate setting. For example it might be:

> \set HISTFILE ~/.psql_history- :DBNAME

as mentioned in the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) for a per-database history file.

Comment: I don't have any `~/.psqlrc` file(did `ls -a` in `~`). Inside the prompt I can do `SHOW hba_file;` to find the location of the `pg_hba.conf` file. Is there an equivalent command to show the `HISTFILE`? (`SHOW hist_file;`  or `SHOW HISTFILE;` does not work)

Comment: Does `echo $PSQL_HISTORY` show an alternate path to your .psql_history?

Comment: It just prints a blank line. But I've found the solution, see qqx's answer.

Comment: Same for me. only a black file. Did you find the solution?

Comment: @Bentley4, where is this qqx answer? Can you say the solution?

Comment: Thanks @bma for mentioning the environment variable `$PSQL_HISTORY`! That was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I have a server here (Amazon Linux AMI, Centos like) that has no postgres home folder. Still it remembers the history of psql. Using the `locate` command I found the history file located in `/var/lib/pgsql93/.psql_history`. On another machine it's in `/var/lib/pgsql/`. After editing this file, removing all relevant lines, the history was gone.

When the locate command doesn't return results, use the command `updatedb` to create the database for the locate command. You cannot run these commands as user postgres btw.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify /etc/passwd.
Put the location of your pgsql folder on postgres line and try :
grep postgres /etc/passwd | cut -d ':' -f 6

Answer (score 0):

Some other answers have hinted at this and mentioned how to look up where the `.psql_history` file is kept in the case that your postgres user doesn't have a home directory (ie. you don't have `/home/postgres/`), but they haven't mentioned what the default location is.

To save time looking at the directory references, your `.psql_history` file (and `.bash_history` file for the postgres user) can be found at `var/lib/postgresql/`

Also note that if you are using `ls` to check this directory to include the `-a` flag as they are still hidden files.

Comment: None of the directories exist on CentOS 7. I would like to clear the history because it contains password entries.

Answer (score 0):

For a docker postgres container, you may be signed in as root. As a result you should look for the .psql_history in /root.

(To see it you will need to ls -a):

```
ls -la /root/
```

You will need to install a text editor probably. Use yum, apk or apt, etc depending on your distro.

If you're not sure which distro you're on:

```
cat /etc/os-release
```